# undefined method pluralize for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pluralize

I'm trying to test a method in my console, but even the basic pluralize -

```
pluralize(1, 'person')
```

wont work..

Output:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'pluralize' for main:Object
from (pry):42:in '<main>'
```

but `helper.method(:pluralize)` shows me : `Method: ActionView::Base(ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper)#pluralize`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The helpers aren't included by default in the console. You can include them first and it'll work:

```
>> include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
>> pluralize(1, 'person')
# => "1 person"
```

Or, you can use the `helper` object which Rails gives you in the console:

```
>> helper.pluralize(1, 'person')
# => "1 person"
```

Comment: i was doing `include TextHelper`.. Didn't know i had to include the whole thing. Thanks Dylan.

Comment: This breaks MVC, but  I do it all the time :-0